# Why am i getting depth as Zero in recursive function python

Tags: python, recursion

i am getting depth as zero for root = [1,2,3,4,5] binary tree
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/78K9w.png)

```py
class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        depth = 0
        self.dfs(root,depth)
        return depth
    def dfs(self,root,depth):
        if root is None:
            return depth

        left = root.left
        right = root.right
    
        l = self.dfs(left,depth)
        r = self.dfs(right,depth)
        depth = max(depth,l+r)
    
        return 1+ max(l,r)
```

Comment: You need to assign the returned value of the `self.dfs` function call to `depth` variable otherwise it will always return 0 (ie `depth = self.dfs(root, depth)`)

Comment: Fix the code indentation.

Comment: `depth` is a local variable inside the `diameterOfBinaryTree()` function.  Calling `self.dfs()` will not affect that variable.  So when you return it, it is always zero.

Comment: Argument is by value. You pass 0 in the form of the local variable depth and  that function has its own argument called depth but these are not the same variable. They just happen to be named the same. `dfs` returns the result, but you do nothing with it and return 0 instead. Btw the argument `depth` is never altered and if you used it  adding 1 to the max would be redundant since you should add to depth in the recursive calls.

Comment: Passing `depth` (or rather the diameter) on the way down won't do you any good; I don't see how it could be computed other than going up; rather have dfs return 2 values: the height from the node and the max diameter.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass any value down (and I'm not sure passing the diameter down is possible or makes sense); rather have your recursive function return the height under the current node, and the max diameter found while going back up from the leaves to this node:

```
def dfs(root):
    if root is None:
        return -1, 0
    l_height, l_diameter = dfs(root.left)
    r_height, r_diameter = dfs(root.right)
    return (1 + max(l_height, r_height),
            max(l_diameter, r_diameter, 2 + l_height + r_height))
```